# How to be more DRY in Propel's schema.xml?

Tags: php, xml, database-schema, propel

I have the usual "schema.xml" in Propel and notice that there are some repeated blocks of XML markup. I have a table, which in turn has 10 child tables - and each child needs some code to specify that relationship (inside a `<table>`):

```
<column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" />
<foreign-key foreignTable="process_step">
    <reference local="id" foreign="id" />
</foreign-key>
<behavior name="delegate">
    <parameter name="to" value="process_step" />
</behavior>
```

I'm therefore putting the above code in a separate file, "process-step-pk.xml", and then add the following to the start of my schema.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
    <!ENTITY process_step_pk SYSTEM "process-step-pk.xml">
]>
```

Finally where I wish to insert the XML snippet, I use an entity reference:

```
<table name="process_step_load">
    &process_step_pk;
    <column name="url" type="varchar" size="1024" />
    <column name="method" type="varchar" size="6" required="true" default="get" />
</table>
```

Here's what I get when I try to build my classes:

> [PHP Error] DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Internal error: xmlSchemaVDocWalk, there is at least one entity reference in the node-tree currently being validated. Processing of entities with this XML Schema processor is not supported (yet). Please substitute entities before validation.. [line 477 of (root)/vendor/propel/generator/lib/task/AbstractPropelDataModelTask.php]
>
> Execution of target "sql-template" failed for the following reason: (root)/vendor/propel/generator/build-propel.xml:209:10: XML schema file ((root)/db/schema.xml) does not validate. See warnings above for reasons validation failed (make sure error_reporting is set to show E_WARNING if you don't see any).
>
> [phingcall] (root)/vendor/propel/generator/build-propel.xml:209:10: XML schema file ((root)/db/schema.xml) does not validate. See warnings above for reasons validation failed (make sure error_reporting is set to show E_WARNING if you don't see any).
>
> Execution of target "sql" failed for the following reason: (root)/vendor/propel/generator/build-propel.xml:194:26: Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.
>       [phing] (root)/vendor/propel/generator/build-propel.xml:194:26: Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.

The key phrase is **Processing of entities with this XML Schema processor is not supported (yet)**, so it knows what I am attempting to do! Has anyone a suggestion as to how I can accomplish this another way?

I'm using PHP 5.3.25 on the console, on OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? This may be a `libxml` error.

Comment: Good point @twigmac, hadn't thought to include that; added now.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error in my environment, which employs PHP 5.3.3 on Debian squeeze. It seems as if the error traces down to libxml and sadly I don't have any other idea than modifying or re-writing the Propel task by overriding the xml validation part. I guess that's what you COULD do but it's not what you WANT to do.

Comment: Thanks for trying it. I don't have immediate access to 5.4 or 5.5, but I can set up a VM if it would stand a chance of fixing the problem. Do you think it might? (I'd assumed it was something in Propel that was the problem).

Comment: I don't think it would solve the problem. There is [room for speculation](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=340316) on whether Propel or libxml should substitute the entities. I think Propel should. Maybe you could check and submit your requirement at a [Propel mailing list](http://propelorm.org/support.html) or as a [Propel bug](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues)?

Comment: Heh, I'd say libxml should `:)`. However, thanks for that suggestion, I will indeed raise a bug. If you wouldn't mind transferring that to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Twigmac suggests in the comments that this problem is to do with libxml, and that Propel would need to read the schema using another mechanism if entity support is required. When I get a moment, I'll raise an enhancement ticket with the Propel project.